# Multiple components binding with the same reactive form control update issue

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In some situations, we could need to have multiple form components binded to the same form control. And I'm confused by the angular way of handling this case:

When changing one of the components value, the form value is changed but not the other components values.

The workaround I did in this case is to patch the from with the form value, which is ugly:

```
this.form.patchValue(this.form.value);
```

[Here is a stackblitz demo for my issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-components-same-form-control), I added the workaround for the input change not the select for better understanding.

Is there an elegant way to handle this case with angular reactive forms?

Comment: have you tried using ``.setValue()`` ? also can you share your form code as well ? because without that it is difficult to help

Comment: @CruelEngine there is already a stackblitz code link in the question.

Comment: As an alternative way, you can set `[(ngModel)]` for both fields and bind them to the same variable, like here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-components-same-form-control-3xfuez?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @P.S - I know your comment is old, but the question does specify that the solution should use reactive forms. `ngModel` would be the template-driven way of doing things.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A nice reactive solution which would not require adding any `(change)` listeners, would be to create two separate name controls, and keep them in sync by subscribing to `valueChanges` stream.

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, NgModule, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      nameText: '',
      nameSelect: '',
    })

    const text = this.form.get('nameText');
    const select = this.form.get('nameSelect');

    text.valueChanges.subscribe(v => select.setValue(v, { emitEvent: false }));
    select.valueChanges.subscribe(v => text.setValue(v, { emitEvent: false }));
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  When you change the input, the select changes : <br>
  <input type="text" formControlName="nameText"><br>
  When you change the select, the input does not change : <br>
  <select formControlName="nameSelect">
    <option value="value1">value1</option>
    <option value="value2">value2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-components-same-form-control-hrwynf)

Answer (score 13):

I solved it by just using AbstractControl
valueChanges and setValue APIs. In this approach you don't have to use 2 separate form controls, you can have any number of components bound to the same reactive form control.

```
this.form.get('formControlName').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.form.get('formControlName').setValue(value, { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false, emitModelToViewChange: true });
  }, error => {}, () => { });
```

The key here is the options param of setValue, this will prevent the recusive execution of valuesChanges until overflow.

```
{ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false, emitModelToViewChange: true }
```

Comment: Don't forget to unsubscribe! Especially if this form will be shown a lot in your application - you'll get a memory leak in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a generic solution: I'm using a JSON var "prevData" to remember the previous value and not loop indefinitely:

```
this.prevData = "";

this.form.valueChanges.subscribe( 
  
  data => {  
    let str = JSON.stringify(data); 
    if (str != this.prevData){
      this.prevData = str;
      this.form.patchValue(data);
    } 
  }
);
```

Comment: This does not look to me as a good solution. Why didn't you use `{ emitEvent: false }` option ?